# Insert single quote with sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to add some text on a line:

```
sudo sed -i '5imytext 16/16' /file
```

Now I've added `mytext 16/16` on line 5 of the file, but I actually want to add the text `'mytext' 16/16` (`mytext` between single quotes).

I tried

```
sudo sed -i '5i'mytext' 16/16' /file
```

but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The single quotes that you're trying to use in your insertion string are interfering with the ones around the sed command.

The simplest thing to do is to use different quotes around your sed command:

```
"5i'mytext' 16/16"
```

Normally it's best to use single quotes around a sed command but it would be more tricky in this case:

```
'5i'"'"'mytext'"'"' 16/16'
```

Basically, you need to put the single quotes inside double quotes somehow and in this case there's no reason not to double quote the whole command.

As suggested by 123 in the comments, an alternative would be to put your sed command into a script file:

```
5i'mytext' 16/16
```

Then use the `-f` switch to sed:

```
sed -f script
```

This avoids the need to use two kinds of quotes.

Comment: The simplest and a clearer way is to just put the command in a file and run `sed -f scriptfile file`

Comment: Yeah, or I guess you could use a heredoc. This looks like the closest thing to what the OP had to begin with though.

Answer (score 2):

Use double quote in these cases. Because:

1. Single quote can't have single quote inside it. (`'\''` won't work)
2. Double quote can have both single quote and double quote inside it. (`"'\""` will work)

Example:

```
sudo sed -i "5i'mytext' 16/16" /file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use double quotes around your sed command, but that won't help you if you also need to insert double quotes. An alternative would be to use: `\x27`

Example: `echo a|sed 's/a/\x27/'` ➡ `'`